Ubuntu 22.04 boot to console after GUI starts. How to make it stay with GUI?
After upgrading to 22.04 from 20.04, I got blank screen, after quite some trouble-shooting effort, I modified /etc/default/grub file to boot to console, and could then manually startx. Everything works fine except the system does not lock after suspend, making it unsecured. So after upgrading to 22.04.1, I want to restore to GUI by reversing the change in the above file.
But it doesn't work, after the Ubuntu GUI loading screen, it goes back to a console. I still have to run startx to be back to the Ubuntu Desktop. I even removed ubuntu-desktop. But was surprised to see the GUI boot screen still appears before ending at a console, and also startx works. How could it start when I have removed it? I paste the above file below. What could I have missed?  Thanks for any insight!
--- /etc/default/grub -----
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
# uncommented on 9/10/24 to revert back to GUI at boot
# GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
# changed to below on 6/6/2024 to get rid of 'ACPI BIOS Error (bug)' at boot
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash loglevel=3"
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodesget loglevel=3"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

